# How to properly create an array of predefined JObjects?

Tags: java

I am creating a `javax.swing.JPanel`, using Netbeans 8.2 and the GUI Builder plugin. For ease of access, I want to create an array of all `javax.swing.JTextField` objects in the class, but for now I've remained unsuccessful. I tried to reference all objects by their variable name, but only gotten `null` elements in the array.

Something I tried:

```
public class TarifDialog extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public TarifDialog() {

         initComponents();    //Auto generated initializer created by GUI Builder
    }

[...]

    private javax.swing.JTextField tfALBeschreibung;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tfALName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tfALPreis;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tfALSchluessel;

    private javax.swing.JTextField[] textFields = new javax.swing.JTextField[] 
        {tfALBeschreibung, 
            tfALName, 
            tfALPreis,
            tfALSchluessel
        };
}
```

Like I said, this only creates an array full of NullPointers and I'm out of my depth. How do I properly create an array that holds those JTextFields?

Comment: I believe you are creating the array too early. Try adding the fields to your array only after initialising them

Comment: @Paul Cosma Thanks, that was indeed the culprit. Now I feel relieved and stupid at the same time.

Comment: Yup, only after initializing them do they point to an object, and when you add an object to an array, what you are really doing is telling the array to look at this spot in memory for that object.